# ResultSetExtractor in jdbcTemplate throwing compilation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, jdbctemplate

I was trying out a demo on how to use `ResultSetExtractor` but I am not able to make it work.

Below is the code I tried:

```
public String retrieveDeptName(final int deptId){
    String deptName = (String)jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
                throws SQLException {               
            return con.prepareStatement(SELECT_DEPT);
        }
    }, new PreparedStatementSetter() {          
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setInt(1, deptId);
        }
    },new ResultSetExtractor() {
        @Override
        public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {               
            if (rs.next()) {
              return rs.getLong(2);
            }               
            return null;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(deptName);
}
```

The error is:

`The method update(String, Object[], int[]) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (new PreparedStatementCreator(){}, new PreparedStatementSetter(){}, new ResultSetExtractor(){})`

Though clear enough, I am surprised how this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/PreparedStatementCreatorAndPreparedStatementSetter.htm) works then?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method `update(String, Object[], int[])` in the type `JdbcTemplate` is not applicable for the arguments (`new PreparedStatementCreator(){}, new PreparedStatementSetter(){}, new ResultSetExtractor(){}`)

The message is pretty clear. If you look at the [API for JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html?is-external=true), you can see there *is* no `update` method that takes those three parameter types:

```
int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc)
int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)
int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementSetter pss)          
int update(String sql)
int update(String sql, Object... args)
int update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)
int update(String sql, PreparedStatementSetter pss)
```

---

> Though clear enough, I am surprised how this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/PreparedStatementCreatorAndPreparedStatementSetter.htm) works then?

The example does *not* use `update`, it uses `query`, which *does* have an overload with those arguments.

```
 T query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementSetter pss, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a refactor to your code, to be more readable

Your code uses the `update` method

```
String deptName = (String)jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
```

and you are doing a query **SELECT_DEPT**, update and select? It has no sense.

**JdbcTemplate** has the **query** method and it supports or is able to work with a **ResultSetExtractor**