# Spring getJdbcTemplate().update insert dynamic object

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I never met such a prob before, google doesn't help.

I use Spring Framework, `JdbcDaoSupport`, `getJdbcTemplate().update()` method.
I have a dynamic query with 2 optional parameters.

Don't know the right way to input the dynamic object.
this is how i try:

```
    StringBuilder sbUserRegQuery = new StringBuilder();
    sbUserRegQuery.append("INSERT INTO users (username, password , email, enabled, datetime_condo_changed, datetime_last_login");
    if(user.getCondo_id()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", condo_id");
    if(user.getProvider()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", provider");
    sbUserRegQuery.append(")");
    sbUserRegQuery.append(" VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ?");
    if(user.getCondo_id()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", ?");
    if(user.getProvider()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", ?"); //default - "local"
    sbUserRegQuery.append(");");

        Object regObject = new Object[]{
            user.getUsername(), PasswordEncoderGenerator.main(user.getPassword()), user.getEmail(), enabled, user.getDatetime_condo_changed(), currentTimeStamp, user.getCondo_id()
        };

       int row = getJdbcTemplate().update(sbUserRegQuery.toString(), regObject, user.getCondo_id(), user.getProvider());
```

i.e. i'm trying to insert the dynamic object after the `regObject`.
But, in this case, the order of dynamic object can be changed, and query fails..

**How to solve this case?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169818/make-dynamic-query-with-jdbctemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it by using the conditional checks on creating the SQL but you then don't do that for the variable arguments being passed into the update() method.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

```
StringBuilder sbUserRegQuery = new StringBuilder();
sbUserRegQuery.append("INSERT INTO users (username, password , email, enabled, datetime_condo_changed, datetime_last_login");
if(user.getCondo_id()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", condo_id");
if(user.getProvider()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", provider");
sbUserRegQuery.append(")");
sbUserRegQuery.append(" VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ?");
if(user.getCondo_id()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", ?");
if(user.getProvider()!=null) sbUserRegQuery.append(", ?");
sbUserRegQuery.append(");");

ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
params.add(user.getUsername());
params.add(PasswordEncoderGenerator.main(user.getPassword()));
params.add(user.getEmail());
params.add(enabled);
params.add(user.getDatetime_condo_changed());
params.add(currentTimeStamp);
if(user.getCondo_id()!=null) params.add(user.getCondo_id());
if(user.getProvider()!=null) params.add(user.getProvider());

int row = getJdbcTemplate().update(sbUserRegQuery.toString(), params.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the error you are getting ???.

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225512/resultsetextractor-in-jdbctemplate-throwing-compilation-error)
There is no update method with four parameters in jdbcTemplate API.You are mentioning four parameters..

Comment: invalid values, cause positions of "condo_id" and "provider" are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution will be suitable for Your problem, but in my projects I use "inserting" construction that looks like this:

```
public void insert(User u) {
    final String sql = "insert into user(firstName, lastName, email, password) values(?,?,?,?)";

    final String firstName = u.getFirstName();
    final String lastName = u.getLastName();
    final String email = u.getEmail();
    final String password = u.getPassword();

    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql,
                    new String[] { "id" });
            ps.setString(1, firstName);
            ps.setString(2, lastName);
            ps.setString(3, email);
            ps.setString(4, password);
            return ps;
        }
    }, idHolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get in console? You‘d better paste it here.
     I suggest you change this:

```
    Object regObject = new Object[]{
        user.getUsername(), PasswordEncoderGenerator.main(user.getPassword()), user.getEmail(), enabled, user.getDatetime_condo_changed(), currentTimeStamp, user.getCondo_id()
    };


   int row = getJdbcTemplate().update(sbUserRegQuery.toString(), regObject, user.getCondo_id(), user.getProvider());
```

to:

```
int row = getJdbcTemplate().update(
                    sbUserRegQuery,
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    user.getEmail(),
                    enabled,
                    user.getDatetime_condo_changed(),
                    currentTimeStamp,
                    user.getCondo_id(),
                    user.getCondo_id(),
                    user.getProvider()
);
```